# Как получить масштабирование экрана через Python?

Tags: python, масштабирование, scale

Как получить масштабирование экрана через Python? Не очень бы хотелось подключать **GUI** библиотеки, типа Tkinter и тому подобного, разве что PyQt5 (использую в проекте).

[image: 125% - то значение, которое я хочу получить]

В данном случае я хочу получить значение 125% в любом виде.

Comment: В проекте вы используете PyQt5 ? Если да, то расскажите еще раз, что вы хотите получить и при наступлении каких событий вы это хотите получить.

Comment: вон тот ответ не подойдёт ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50253948/query-windows-10-8-monitor-scaling-from-python-script

Comment: Интик, похоже, это действительно то, что мне нужно. В проекте с PyQt5 мне это нужно для резайза текста в зависимости от масштабирования экрана. Возможности сделать это автоматически я пока не нашел

Answer (score 0):

```
import ctypes

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
scale_factor = user32.GetDpiForSystem()

print('Масштабирование экрана: {}%'.format(scale_factor/96*100))
```